# PHP - How to access a object created by an array

Tags: php, class, oop, object

I'm quite new to using OOP and wanted to create a simple cardgame.
I got the following code:

```
class card{

  private $suit;
  private $rank;

  public function __construct($suit, $rank){
      $this->suit = $suit;
      $this->rank = $rank;
  }

  public function test(){
      echo $this->suit.' '.$this->rank;
  }
}

class deck{

  private $suits = array('clubs',   'diamonds', 'hearts', 'spades');
  private $ranks = array(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A');

  public function create_deck(){
     $cards = array();
     foreach($this->suits as $suit) {
        foreach ($this->ranks as $rank) {
           $cards[] = new card($suit, $rank);
        }
     }
     print_r($cards);
  } 
 }
```

Say, for example that my class card had a function for dealing a card.
How do I deal a king of hearts? which is already created but I don't know how to access it.

Comment: `$card = new card('hearts', 'K');` will deal the king of hearts and assign it to the `$card` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function for dealing a card should probably be in the `deck` class, not the `card` class. It would be something like:

```
public function deal_card() {
    $suit = $this->suits[array_rand($this->suits, 1)];
    $rank = $this->ranks[array_rand($this->ranks, 1)];
    return new card($suit, $rank);
}
```

Note that this has no memory of which cards were dealt. The `deck` class should probably have a `private $cards` property containing an array of all the cards (you can fill it in in the contructor, using a loop like in your `create_deck` function). Then when you deal a card, you can remove it from this array:

```
public function deal_card() {
    if (count($this->cards) > 0) {
        $index = array_rand($this->cards, 1); // pick a random card index
        $card = $this->cards[$index]; // get the card there
        array_splice($this->cards, $index, 1); // Remove it from the deck
        return $card;
    } else {
        // Deck is empty, nothing to deal
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate an object like this:

```
$card = new card('hearts', 'K');
```